# How to determine the limit of a recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the limit of the recursive sequence

$a_1=2$
 $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + 6)$

$n\ge 2$

I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Should have been n-1 not n+1

Comment: Hint: The sequences $a_n $ and $a_{n-1} $ converge to the same limit.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the recurrence is easy enough to solve for explicitly:
\begin{align*}
a_{n} & =\left(a_{n-1}+6\right)/2\\
 & =\left(\left(a_{n-2}+6\right)/2+6\right)/2\\
 & =\cdots
\end{align*}
(can you figure out what $a_{n}$ is in terms of $a_{1}=2$?) This
expression is $a_{n}=6-2^{3-n}$ (I leave it here so you can check
your work). Take limits to see what you get:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}6-2^{3-n}=\cdots
$$

---

An alternative approach is to assume that the sequence has a limit, $a_n\rightarrow a$. But then the recurrence becomes (taking limits on both sides)
$$
a=(a+6)/2.
$$
Solving for $a$, this tells you what the limit of the sequence is (**assuming that it has a limit**!)